# What does it mean whether network device is Loopback?

Tags: networking, loopback

Does it mean that the Loopback device handles the request like `ping localhost` ?

If so, there should be at least one device that's loopback,but seems none of my two network device is Loopback:

```
rpcap://\Device\NPF_{45D5ADA0-095E-49F3-BEA1-E8754390F2D4}
        Description: Network adapter 'Intel(R) PRO/Wireless 2200BG Network Conne
ction (Microsoft's Packet Scheduler) ' on local host
        Loopback: no

rpcap://\Device\NPF_{783C5467-4026-473C-86A0-5E5A3708C624}
        Description: Network adapter 'Realtek RTL8169/8110 Family Gigabit Ethern
et NIC                                 (Microsoft's Packet Scheduler) ' on local
 host
        Loopback: no
```

Can someone clarify all this?

Answer (score 3):

None of your physical devices will be a loopback device.

"In TCP/IP a loopback device is a virtual network interface implemented in software only and not connected to any hardware, but which is fully integrated into the computer system's internal network infrastructure. Any traffic that a computer program sends to the loopback interface is immediately received on the same interface."

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loopback

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure, but I have understood that loopback device is not a real device, but a virtual one. It's purpose is to be a fake device that can quickly transfer signals, streams, etc. from a machine to itself.