# How to send to the "loopback interface"?

Tags: network-adapter, localhost, loopback

Does it mean the same as send to `localhost` ?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://superuser.com/questions/137846/what-does-it-mean-whether-network-device-is-loopback

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Effectively, yes it does mean the same thing, though as @quack points out it's not always as straightforward as that.

[Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loopback)

Comment: I like this **Simple** answer lot!

Answer (score 7):

Kind of.  *localhost* is the customary hostname for *127.0.0.1* which is the customary IP address assigned to the *loopback interface*.  The *loopback* is like a virtual network adapter that lets your computer talk to itself via typical networking protocols.

While *127.0.0.1* is the most common IPv4 address for the loopback interface, any address in the 127/8 network (meaning any IP address between 127.0.0.1 and 127.255.255.254) is in the *loopback network* and can be used as loopback addresses.

Similarly, any other valid hostname may be assigned to *127.0.0.1* via DNS or your computer's *hosts* file.  Any access to those names will access the loopback interface as well.

It is also possible, though rare, to redefine *localhost* to point to some other non-loopback IP address.  But most networking software doesn't expect this and it may cause things to fail unexpectedly.